# Importing all contacts from address book with Swift to a table view

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, addressbook

I am quite new with programming with swift. Im trying to create a UIView, where i have a UITableView and show all the contacts in the user's address book.

I have watched and read countless tutorials in 2 days know and i cannot seem to be able to get it working.

I am trying to use Xcode's built in **addressbook** and **addressbookUI** frameworks.

Does anyone have a tutorial or perhaps even a ready solution regarding this specific issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some of your existing to code to see if theres something wrong which can be fixed.

Comment: Hi,

At the moment what I have looks like this:
https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/blob/master/SystemFrameworksDemo/SystemFrameworksDemo/AddressBookViewController.swift

I have connected a button and a table to this successfully.
The build succeeds and the app opens, but when i try to click the button to execute the action, the console brings up "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) " which i tried to solve by searching this site but could not do anything about it

Comment: @JanivDavid, I ran the github code you linked and it works fine.  As Stewartside said, you should post the code that is giving you a problem.